# Combinatorics. Could somebody explain how binomial theorem is applied here?

Tags: combinatorics

I do not understand this solution and this formula and why we are using (1+1)^n...
I need some help to get an idea of what is going on here
Thanks

[image]

Comment: This is just the binomial theorem about $(a+b)^n$, with $a=b=1$.

Comment: Please give this a title that explains what your question is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can count the number of subsets of a finite set of size $n$ in two different ways.

---

The first is counting the number of subsets of each size, from $0$-element subsets to $n$-element subsets. Since there are $\binom{n}{k}$ subsets of size $k$, the total is

$$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}$$

---

The second method is to think about constructing the subset. For of the $n$ elements, we can either include it in the subset or not - $2$ possibilities. We make $n$ such decisions, each with two possibilities, and this series of $n$ decisions uniquely determines the subset, so there are $2^n$ such subsets.

---

Because we counted the same thing in two different ways, our answers must be equal, so $$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}=2^k$$

You can build your intuition on this by playing around with [Pascal's triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle).

Answer (score 0):

first assume one element can be in subsets or not be in subsets so we have 1+1 state now 
we have n element so (1+1)...(1+1)=(1+1)^n and this is number of subsets.
(sorry for my bad english)